# How to implement Fast ICA on multiple wav files?

Tags: ica

I am doing an exercise wherein I have three wav files which comes from recordings from three microphones on an event. I need to implement Fast ICA to decompose the original signals using the three wav files.

I understand what Fast ICA is and how it works. But I don't understand how to decompose sound signals from three sound files.

All the example codes I see either uses and decomposes a single wav file to its component or generate and mix signals then try to unmix them using Fast ICA.

Any inputs or links that would point me to clues on how to do this are very great help.

Also, I am tasked to remix the separated signals and print the residuals. Any idea what residuals are and how to get them?

I'm implementing this on Python so it would be great if the links uses Python too.

Answer (score 0):

This is trivially solved in MATLAB by using this. There is a version in Phyton, though i suggest you to use my recommendation.

There is a redundancy here. If you are using [ICA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_component_analysis), you are intending to be using several vectors. 
Do you understand, why?.

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/linkexchange/links/2115-the-fastica-package-for-matlab
http://www.cis.hut.fi/projects/ica/fastica/

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you want to know how to unmix convolutional mixtures (versus artificially instanteous mixtures). If you want to decompose three signals, what is the matter with using FastICA on those three microphone signals?
I have implemented a Python version here on 2 "microphones" - which I artificially mixed, from two audio sources. I then decompose the two audio sources from the 2 mixed .wav files. 
http://fab.cba.mit.edu/classes/MAS.864/people/Yada.Pruksachatkun/ICA.html